# Why is "swindle" different in the racket interpreter than in drracket?

Tags: racket

Can someone explain the difference between using drracket with swindle (any of the versions) and firing up the interpreter as: racket -I swindle

Many expressions evaluate the same in both environments, but some don't.  For example:

(let-syntax ((let* (syntax-rules () ((let* a b) "You used let*")))) (let* 3 4))

... evaluates to "You used let*" in every scheme-based language I tried in drracket.  However, it fails in the interpreter brought up by "racket -I swindle" on the command line with the error

; readline-input:1:20: syntax-rules: unbound identifier;
;  also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in the transformer phase
;   at: syntax-rules
;   in: (syntax-rules () ((let* a b) "You used let*"))
; [,bt for context]

Comment: Racket Q&A happens on the slack, email-list or IRC 

it is better to ask on one of those

Ask questions at 

a) Racket Slack Signup: https://racket-slack.herokuapp.com/ then you can login to https://racket.slack.com/
b) mailing list
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users/join  (no google ID required)
 c) Google Group  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users/ (same content as mailing-list)
d) IRC #Racket channel on freenode.

You can also search
* documentation https://docs.racket-lang.org/
* mailing list https://groups.google.com/g/racket-users

Comment: sorry I forgot no formatting in comments on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example uses `syntax-rules` at phase 1 (aka the "for-syntax phase", aka the "transformer phase"), but it appears that the `swindle` module (unlike `racket/base` and `racket`) does not provide any bindings for-syntax. (It looks like `swindle` uses an old technique to provide phase-1 bindings that works for modules written in the `swindle` language but not for a REPL started with `racket -l swindle`.)

One workaround is to evaluate

```
(require (for-syntax racket/base))
```

before evaluating your example, and then your example should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks very much, and this does show me how to get the example to work, which is great.  But I still don't understand why there's a difference between "swindle" in DrRacket (even the interpreter window in DrRacket) and "swindle" in the console interpreter.   Can you clarify?  And how can I discover what exact language features I'm getting in DrRacket so I can recreate them in the interpreter (which I can run in a shell script)?